# Can I have a different xml files with color in Android?

Tags: android

I have an xml file with color in my Android app.
Can I choose one or the other in code?

Something like:

```
(if value == 0) {
   // I choose the file 'a'
} else {
  // I choose the file 'b'
}
```

Is this possible??

Thank in advance.

Comment: Yes, inflate the file you need.

Comment: The solution for me is use themes. Thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different *names* for your colors in a single resource file, cf http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Example:

XML

```
<resources>
  <color
    name="color_a">hex_color</color>
  <color
    name="color_b">hex_color</color>
</resources>
```

JAVA

```
if (value == 0) color = R.color.color_a;
else  color = R.color.color_b;
```

Comment: The solution for me is use themes. Thank all.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v;
if(value == 0){
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_yellow, null);
}else{
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_green, null);
}
// do stuff with view
```

Comment: yes your edit answer now ok. Before you have done a little mistake. +1 for you

Comment: yes I have do this. because in previous you have done little mistake my friend. I have also +1 for your answer. though you have edited your answer I have deleted my answer. Don't worry dude

Comment: I noticed immediately after I submitted it, it's ok ;)

Comment: Hi Nfear, thank you, but that solution requires me to maintain two layout, the layout_yellow and the layout_green. The idea is to have only one layout and several file with the colors.

Comment: The solution for me is use themes. Thank all.